# Unable to Run Simulator in Mac OS X EL CAPTIAN AND XCODE VERSION 7.3.1

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode7, xcode8

Please help me with this issue.

While running the simulator in Xcode. I am getting Following  error

Simulator cannot be opened because of a problem.

Check with the developer to make sure Simulator works with this version of OS X. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and OS X.

Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

I tried to reinstall so many time.. with different version of Xcode and ruined with IOS 9.3 and 8.4.

Comment: Ive seen this issue. Try deleting all simulators and recreating them from scratch.

Comment: i tired it. and installed again but same error

Comment: Does it persist after reboot? I found processes i the process list associated with dead simulators that had to be cleared to solve this error.